# Lapack gcc on Mac OS

Tags: c++, gcc, lapack

I am trying to compile my C++ code with gcc against the Accelerate framework in order to make use of Lapack. However I receive the following error message:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vBasicOps.h: In function ‘vUInt16 vU16HalfMultiply(vUInt16, vUInt16)’:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/vBasicOps.h:377:84: note: use -flax-vector-conversions to permit conversions between vectors with differing element types or numbers of subparts
   vUInt16   __vbasicops_vB) { return _mm_mullo_epi16(__vbasicops_vA, __vbasicops_vB); }
```

I found only the suggestion to add "-D__ACCELERATE__" as flag, but this raises a bunch of "not declared in this scope"-errors, e.g. ‘__CLPK_integer’ was not declared in this scope for a variable declared just in my main.

Adding "-flax-vector-conversions" as a flag resolves my issue, however I am not particularly sure how safe this is? Thanks!